# Select IF another fields value is a specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an application that automatically tallies up the time spent for each user.  Each user

Here is the query

```
SELECT
  ServiceBase.User
  ,ServiceBase.Time
  ,ServiceBase.BillingType
from ServiceBase
```

And here is the output

```
User 1  | Time
User 2  | Time
User 3  | Time
        | Total Time
```

I'm looking to add another column that splits the Time based on a BillingType without editing the actual application code.  It will read in a new select field and automatically tally the values, so Im hoping to just use an IF inside the query to get my results to show in the application.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  ServiceBase.User
  ,ServiceBase.Time
  ,ServiceBase.BillingType
  ,Select If(ServiceBase.BillingType = 'Fixed'){ echo ServiceBase.Time; }else{ echo 0;}
from ServiceBase
```

To get a result like so:

```
User 1  | Time           | Fixed Time
User 2  | Time           | Fixed Time
User 3  | Time           | Fixed Time
        | Total Time     | Total Fixed Time
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `CASE` for IFs within a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
  ServiceBase.User
  ,ServiceBase.Time
  ,ServiceBase.BillingType
  ,CASE WHEN ServiceBase.BillingType = 'Fixed' THEN ServiceBase.Time ELSE 0 END AS [Fixed Time]
FROM ServiceBase
```

Comment: You need to remove the extra "SELECT" before the CASE

Comment: True. Thanks @pmbAustin.

Comment: @MrLahey the best way to say thank you on SO is to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT
  ServiceBase.User
  ,ServiceBase.Time
  ,ServiceBase.BillingType
  ,CASE WHEN ServiceBase.BillingType = 'Fixed' THEN ServiceBase.Time ELSE 0 END
from ServiceBase
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the **case when construct**

```
SELECT
  ServiceBase.User
  ,ServiceBase.Time
  ,ServiceBase.BillingType
  ,case when ServiceBase.BillingType = 'Fixed' then ServiceBase.Time else 0 end
from ServiceBase
```